# Dependabot not checking Next.js version

Tags: next.js, dependabot

I have a `dependabot.yml` file under `.github` folder in my Next.js project with the following simple and basic config:

```yaml
# Basic set up for three package managers

version: 2
updates:

  # Maintain dependencies for npm
  - package-ecosystem: "npm"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: "daily"
```

But it never check new versions for `next` package, why?

Comment: The second question "What is the best way for me to keep Next.js up to date?" is opinion based and might lead to the closure of the post.

Comment: Hmm, haven't come back for a while, never knew SO is now this much restricted and not accepting opinion based questions.